# Forces on a Localized Current Distribution

Tags: electromagnetism

I am trying to derive a certain expression from this initial equation:

$$\vec F=\int_V \vec j (\vec r) \times \vec B (\vec r) dV$$
This equation is introduced as the force experienced by a localized current distribution placed in an external magnetic field. But shouldn't the expression be in fact:

$$\vec F=\int_V \vec j (\vec r') \times \vec B (\vec r) dV'$$
The difference being that $\vec r'$ is a vector inside the region where the current charge distribution is. While we use $\vec r$ for the external field. You can't use the same variable for both, because while $\vec r$ can point anywhere in space,which implies the value of $\vec B$ at any point in space, $\vec r'$ should point only in an localized region, if it points out of it, clearly we have no electric current and it doesn't make sense to speak about that.

Then I do a Tailor expansion of the Magnetic field, centered at $\vec r_0=0$. That would give me:

$$\vec B(\vec r) = \frac 1 {0!}\vec B(\vec r)|_{\vec r= \vec r_0}(\vec r - \vec r_0)^0 + \frac 1 {1!} \nabla_\vec r \vec B(\vec r)|_{\vec r= \vec r_0}(\vec r - \vec r_0)^1$$

Then by plugging in $\vec r_0=0$ I get:

$$\vec B(0) +  \nabla_\vec r \vec B(\vec r)|_{\vec r= 0}\vec r $$

Inserting this term in my initial equation, and assigning zero to the first term (since the monopole doesn't exist) I get:

$$\vec F=\int_V \vec j (\vec r') \times \nabla_\vec r \vec B(\vec r)|_{\vec r= 0}\vec r dV'$$

But the proper expression according to what it's given to me is:

$$\vec F=\int_V \vec j (\vec r') \times (\vec r' \nabla_\vec r) \vec B(\vec r)|_{\vec r= 0} dV'$$

As one can see here we have $\vec r'$ instead of $\vec r$ and most importantly we have $(\vec r' \nabla_{\vec r})\vec B(\vec r)|_{\vec r=0}$ instead of $(\nabla_{\vec r})\vec B(\vec r)|_{\vec r=0}) \vec r$. Is it in general true that: $(\nabla \vec a)\vec b = (\vec b \nabla)\vec a$?

My ultimate goals is to show: $$\vec F = \big[\frac 1 2 (\int \vec r' \times \vec j(\vec r')) \times \nabla_{\vec r} \big] \times \vec B(\vec r)|_{\vec r=0}$$

Just to clarify, the first expression regarding the force on a current distribution is the one I find the most, but as I pointed out I think there should be a change of variables between $\vec B$ and $\vec j$. And the main problem I am faced with, has to do with this clash of notations. I hope someone can help me advance further. Physically I understand what we are doing but there is a mathematical problem that I am facing.

Edit:

In theory, I could start from $$\vec F=\int_V \vec j (\vec r') \times (\vec r' \nabla_\vec r) \vec B(\vec r)|_{\vec r= 0} dV'$$ ignoring all what I mentioned above this. But I was confused about the notation of the respective variables and I thought of deriving this expresion myself and then proceed further, but as you can see I get a different expression.

Comment: The force on $j(r)$ is given by the $B$-field at the point $r$, not by the $B$-field  at some other place in space.

Comment: but j(r) and B are two different things in the set up. B field is in the space (produced by some distribution far away) while j(r) is located in a charge distribution, so you cannot have the same variable for both quantities, because while $\vec r$ can point anywhere in space for the B- field, that is not the case for j(r)

Comment: you can for example ask what is the B-field at a point outside the current distribution and what is the current density at a particular point in the current distribution. You need to have two different vectors pointing at two different locations

Comment: at a point $\mathcal P$ the force on an elementary (infinitesimal) current element is $\vec j (\mathcal P) \times \vec B (\mathcal P)$, a vector product of two vectors both taken at the *same* point $\mathcal P$; now sum (integrate) them.